# Do triple-linked graphs exist?

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, topological-graph-theory, knot-link

Lets say that a finite simple graph $G$ is *(intrinsically) fully triple-linked* if for each embedding of $G$ into $\Bbb R^3$ we can find *three* disjoint cycles $C_1,C_2,C_3\subset G$ whose embeddings are *pairwise* linked.

> **Question:** Do fully triple-linked graphs exist?

This is a natural generalization of [intrinsically linked graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linkless_embedding): every embedding of $K_6$ has two linked cycles.
A lot has been written on such generalizations [1].
For example, $K_{10}$ is (partially) triple-linked in the sense that every embedding has three cycles that form a non-split link. This link might however be a "chain" (one cycle linked to two others that are unlinked). Moreover, arbitrarily large non-split links are forced to appear in embeddings of large enough complete graphs, but as far as I know, these might just form "long chains" or perhaps "branching chains". If something has been proven about forcing more complicated links, I was unable to find it.

---

- [1] J. L. Ramírez Alfonsín, *"Knots and links in spatial graphs: A survey"*

Comment: For $n$ large and $K_n\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, we may color every $i\in\binom{[n]}{6}$ with $2^\binom63$ colors indicating which triangles in $K_i$ are linked. Given $c\in\binom{[n]}9$ monochromatic, the only color of $c$ I find hard to produce a full triple-link is if the only link in $[6]$ is $(124,356)$. Can we embed $K_n$ such that the only links in $K_n$ are of index $(i_1i_2i_4,i_3i_5i_6)$ with $i_1<\ldots<i_6$?

Comment: @EdwardH Sorry, I don't understand the comment. Do you assume a particular mapping between the colors $2^{6\choose 3}$ and the vertices in $i\in{[n]\choose 6}$? I don't see what monochromatic implies without knowing the exact mapping. More generally, I don't know what you mean by "the only color of $c$ I find hard to produce a full triple-link". Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

If you restrict to straight-line embeddings (where edges are line segments), then the answer is yes: using the result in [Erdos-Szekeres in high dimensions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/72212/39521) there exists some $n$ such that if you have $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ in general linear position, then 9 of them must form the vertices of a cyclic polytope $(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_9)$.

Consequently, any straight-line embedding of such a $K_n$ contains a $K_9$ forming a cyclic polytope, in which case the triangles $\{ v_1, v_4, v_7 \}, \{ v_2, v_5, v_8 \}, \{ v_3, v_6, v_9 \}$ are pairwise-linked.

---

**[begin non-rigorous section]** It should be possible to adapt this into a topological proof that works for every embedding, but I don't have a complete proof (just a rough outline). In particular, given an embedding of a complete graph $K_n$ (with the vertices labelled by integers $1, \dots, n$), it should be possible to extend this to an immersion of the complete simplicial complex of dimension 2 (where we have triangles as well as vertices and edges).

Then we can colour each set of 4 points (note that we have an order on the underlying vertex set) according to the orientation of the simplicial sphere, and use Ramsey's theorem for 4-sets to guarantee some homogeneous 9-vertex set where all of the 4-vertex subsets have the same orientation. Then it should be possible to prove that this forms a [cyclic polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_polytope), and then we're done by the same argument. **[end non-rigorous section]**